# How to discretize a continuous space for making a histogram?

Tags: c, histogram, discrete-mathematics

I have a random variable that returns real values (`0 to 100`) and I'd like to make a histogram but I'm not been able to make an algorithm (in C) to discretize the result. I tried the following, which gives me `50` on `hist[0]`:

```
for(i=0;i<LEN;i++){
    y = f[i]/X_MAX;
    printf("%e\n",y);
    k = (int) (LEN_HIST*y);
    printf("%d\n",k);
    hist[k]++;
}
```

where `f` is the array with the real numbers, `LEN` is the size of `f` (50), `LEN_HIST` is the size of the histogram array (20), and `X_MAX` is the highest value in `f`.

Comment: What are the printed values for k and y? Also is y float? If all is correct, k should be printing values 0 to 19 and y should be 0 to 1, right?

Comment: Did you initialize `hist` (set everything to 0)?

Comment: Yes, hist is initialized , and k is int and,y and is double

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking about how to do this in C, but for the type of work it looks like you are attempting, I suggest the [ipython](http://ipython.org) scientific computing ecosystem.  You won't end up reinventing the wheel at every turn like you will if you program it in C.  Here is a [tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/swcarpentry/notebooks/blob/master/matplotlib.ipynb) which includes making a histogram.

Comment: What is the type of `y`?  Actually, please show the types of all variables.